# App stops unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to make a simple app that plays random sounds, when the user clicks a button. The app launches without problems, and it will play a random amount of sounds before it crashes. I can't find any similar problems / questions, which is why I'm posting this.

This is my log:

```
08-09 10:10:16.706: D/dalvikvm(265): GC freed 571 objects / 49008 bytes in 128ms
08-09 10:10:18.896: W/MediaPlayer(265): info/warning (1, 44)
08-09 10:10:19.036: I/MediaPlayer(265): Info (1,44)
08-09 10:10:19.036: W/MediaPlayer(265): info/warning (1, 44)
08-09 10:10:19.036: I/MediaPlayer(265): Info (1,44)
08-09 10:10:19.236: W/MediaPlayer(265): info/warning (1, 44)
08-09 10:10:19.336: I/MediaPlayer(265): Info (1,44)
08-09 10:10:19.346: W/MediaPlayer(265): info/warning (1, 44)
08-09 10:10:19.346: I/MediaPlayer(265): Info (1,44)
08-09 10:10:19.746: W/MediaPlayer(265): info/warning (1, 44)
08-09 10:10:19.856: I/MediaPlayer(265): Info (1,44)
08-09 10:10:20.016: W/MediaPlayer(265): info/warning (1, 44)
08-09 10:10:20.166: I/MediaPlayer(265): Info (1,44)
08-09 10:10:20.166: W/MediaPlayer(265): info/warning (1, 44)
08-09 10:10:20.166: I/MediaPlayer(265): Info (1,44)
08-09 10:10:20.396: W/MediaPlayer(265): info/warning (1, 44)
08-09 10:10:20.556: I/MediaPlayer(265): Info (1,44)
08-09 10:10:20.566: W/MediaPlayer(265): info/warning (1, 44)
08-09 10:10:20.566: I/MediaPlayer(265): Info (1,44)
08-09 10:10:20.766: W/MediaPlayer(265): info/warning (1, 44)
08-09 10:10:20.907: I/MediaPlayer(265): Info (1,44)
08-09 10:10:20.907: W/MediaPlayer(265): info/warning (1, 44)
08-09 10:10:20.916: I/MediaPlayer(265): Info (1,44)
08-09 10:10:21.116: W/MediaPlayer(265): info/warning (1, 44)
08-09 10:10:21.236: I/MediaPlayer(265): Info (1,44)
08-09 10:10:21.246: W/MediaPlayer(265): info/warning (1, 44)
08-09 10:10:21.246: I/MediaPlayer(265): Info (1,44)
08-09 10:10:21.406: W/MediaPlayer(265): info/warning (1, 26)
08-09 10:10:21.427: E/MediaPlayer(265): error (1, -17)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265): create failed:
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native  Method)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at     android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:644)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at  com.moer.playsound.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:40)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at  android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.j ava:1659)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1 643)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-09 10:10:21.447: D/MediaPlayer(265):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-09 10:10:21.466: D/AndroidRuntime(265): Shutting down VM
08-09 10:10:21.466: W/dalvikvm(265): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
08-09 10:10:21.476: E/AndroidRuntime(265): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at com.moer.playsound.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-09 10:10:21.496: E/AndroidRuntime(265):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-09 10:10:21.516: I/dalvikvm(265): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
08-09 10:10:21.726: I/dalvikvm(265): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-09 10:10:34.156: I/Process(265): Sending signal. PID: 265 SIG: 9
```

And this is the code:

```
package com.moer.playsound;


import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.Random;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private final int NUM_SOUND_FILES = 8;

private int mfile[] = new int[NUM_SOUND_FILES];
private Random rnd = new Random();
private MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

mfile[0] = R.raw.sound1;  
mfile[1] = R.raw.sound2;  
mfile[2] = R.raw.sound3;
mfile[3] = R.raw.sound4;
mfile[4] = R.raw.sound5;
mfile[5] = R.raw.sound6;
mfile[6] = R.raw.sound7;
mfile[7] = R.raw.sound8;


Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
     mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, mfile[rnd.nextInt(NUM_SOUND_FILES)]);
     mp.seekTo(0);
     mp.start(); 
   }});

} 
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        finish();
 return true;
  }
return false;
}
}
```

I've tried using the wav format instead and decreasing the amount of files used, but it doesn't do anything. I'm new at this, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Is it when you start next sound before the last one has finished?

Comment: Hi. The sound files are about 10kb each. They don't last longer than 2 secs. I triede clicking at a slow rate, but it still crashes. As I pointed out to Aerrow below, it seems like the faster I click, the sooner it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Try with this,

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int[] SOUNDS = new int[] { R.raw.sound1, R.raw.sound2,
            R.raw.sound3, R.raw.sound4, R.raw.sound5, R.raw.sound6,
            R.raw.sound7, R.raw.sound8 };

    // private int mfile[] = new int[NUM_SOUND_FILES];
    private Random rnd = new Random();
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    int flag = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (flag == 0) {
                    Log.v("Flag Values is", flag + "");
                    audioPlaying();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "player is currently Playing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                    flag = 0;
                    audioPlaying();
                }

            }
        });
        // Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        // button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        // public void onClick(View v) {
        //
        // mp.stop();
        // mp.release();
        //
        // }
        // });
    }

    protected void audioPlaying() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int sndToPlay = rnd.nextInt(SOUNDS.length);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, SOUNDS[sndToPlay]);
        mp.seekTo(0);
        mp.start();
        flag++;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // deallocate all memory
        if (mp != null) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
            }
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1585966: Notice my code, here i use two Buttons for my convenience, one for start paying and another once for Stop the player. Change this code as per your needs.

Comment: Thanks. Fast service in here I might say :)

Comment: I tried changing the code, but I'm still getting the same result. The sound files are approximately 10kb each. I'm not sure, but it seems like the faster I click the button, the sooner it crashes.

Comment: @user1585966: I tried with upto 9MB audio file. It wasn't crashed. May i know in which format you have used. Here in my code i user .mp3

Comment: I'm also using mp3. I tried with wav format, but same result. This goes for both the emulator and on my phone.

Comment: @user1585966: if you commenting out the button2 means, the media player won't stop until you click the back button in your emulator/mobile. The audio files are played parallel.

Comment: Ok. I tried it both ways. That is, with and without button2, but I get the same result. Is it because I have to code the mediaplayer in a different way ? You mention it play the files parallel. Could this be the problem ?

Comment: @user1585966: I Edited my code, use the new code, here i used a single button for playing the audio file in random manner

Comment: It works :) Thank you. It takes a little longer to initialise new sounds, but it seems to be working fine now :) It displays a "toast" message saying something like "player still playing". Can I get rid of this message somehow ?

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the toast you included.....sorry about that :) Again, thank you very much.